# How to properly detect closed socket in Python

Tags: python, json, sockets, http, post

I have a python script that emits an `HTTP POST` with json body which I pipe to `netcat`and all works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

body = "{ \"key\": \"Test\", \"value\": \"Test\" }"

print "POST /valSet HTTP/1.1\r"
print "Host: 192.168.10.1\r"
print "Content-Type: application/json\r"
print "Accept: application/json\r"
print "Content-Length: " + str(len(body)+2) + "\r"
print "\r"

print body

$ ./valSet | nc 192.168.10.1 80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Innovix
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

e
{"success": 0}
0
$
```

As you can see above, the `HTTP` code is sent, `netcat` forwards it to port 80, and the response is successful.  More importantly, the connection immediately terminates after the last `0` appears in the chunked response.

However in my setting I can't rely on `netcat` being there, so I need a self-contained program.  I therefore rewrote the above as follows:

```
def set():
    key = raw_input("Key: ")
    val = raw_input("Value: ")
    body = "{ \"key\": \"" + key + "\", \"value\": \"" + val + "\" }"
    send(body)

def send(body):
    s.send("POST /valSet HTTP/1.1\r\n")
    s.send("Host: " + SERVER_IP + "\r\n")
    s.send("Content-Type: application/json\r\n")
    s.send("Accept: application/json\r\n")
    s.send("Content-Length: " + str(len(body)+2) + "\r\n")
    s.send("\r\n")
    s.send(body)

    # Get response
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024) 
        print 'Response:', data
        if not data:
            break

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.connect((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)) 
set()
```

This again works, but with a severe drawback: `recv()` executes twice, then hangs.  On the server side it eventually times out with `Client timed out; closing socket`.

**Question:** Why does the `netcat` version terminate immediately and my python version blocks on `recv()` until the server hangs up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netcat closes the connection because its input (e.g. your python script) finished and thus stdin of netcat got closed. Your python script which tries to send a HTTP request to the server hangs because you do make several mistakes with using HTTP:

- You set content-length to `len(body)+2`, but it it must be only the length of the body, e.g. `len(body)`. That's why the server is still waiting for data from your client.
- You do an HTTP/1.1 request but don't deal with the implicit keep-alive you have but instead expect the server to close the connection. Also you don't deal with chunked responses.

I would recommend to use a http library for doing the hard work, unless you are eager to learn all the details and pitfalls of doing HTTP. In this case I would recommend you read the specification first, e.g. RFC2616 (or better: RFC7230..RFC7235).

Comment: My understanding of `Connection: close` is that (in spite of HTTP 1.1) the connection will not be kept alive after the response is sent.  Your answer implies otherwise?!

Comment: @Fixee: Yes, `connection: close` will make the server close the connection, but you have to specify this explicitly with HTTP/1.1, because it defaults to keep-alive. HTTP/1.0 defaults to close and also does not use chunked encoding and thus makes parsing the response easier.

Comment: As you can see in my question, the server responds with `Connection: close` which I interpreted to mean the server would close the connection at the end of the interaction and not hold the connection open.  But as I've said, the connection persists.  I'm unsure why; the server is proprietary, so it could just be a bug.

Comment: Btw, thank you for your answer: the observation that `netcat` terminates because it sees `EOF` on its `stdin` was insightful (and almost certainly correct).

Comment: @Fixee: the `Connection: close` on the server side means that the server will close the connection after the request and response is done. But, because you send a content length larger than your content, the request is not and the server is still waiting for the promised data and will not close the connection.